# Plot error and blank tab of plot

Tags: seurat, ggplot2

I am trying to plot by using these commands , but this is the error I am getting, and I tried multiple times, even by making the window size larger, the [lot tab is empty/blank too.

```r
plot1 <- VariableFeaturePlot(nsclc.seurat.obj)
LabelPoints(plot = plot1, points = top10, repel = TRUE)***
*When using repel, set xnudge and ynudge to 0 for optimal results
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  Viewport has zero dimension(s)
In addition: Warning message:
Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis*
```

Comment: Welcome @Samia. Could you kindly clarify your study? I get the impression this is a Seurat analysis and I assume you are plotting the PCA. Any further information on the study would help understand the error output. Basically that the PCA is empty "zero dimension(s)" - not good. The error is likely further upstream.